# R: condition coloring points

Tags: r, if-statement, plot

I have a data of temperatures and dates, I used functions hwmid and hwmi. I plotted it and now I would like to color only certain ones, but only if three points suffice the condition.

Example: my limit is 30 and if 3 sequential points in the graph are over 30, they color red.

My whole formula:

```
library(extRemes)
library(in2extRemes)

lj <- read.table("C:/Users/matejaz/Desktop/hwmi/lj.csv", sep = ";", quote = "\"") #my data
tiid <- lj[,1]

jan1980 <- which(tiid == 19800101)
jan2003 <- which(tiid == 20030101)
dec2003 <- which(tiid == 20031231)
dec2011 <- which(tiid == 20111231)

Temp <- lj[jan2003:dec2003, 2] 
Tref <- lj[jan1980:dec2011 , 2] 

##hwmid calculation
hwmidLj2003 <- hwmid(1980, Tref, 2003, Temp)
hwmiLj2003 <- hwmi(1980, Tref, 2003, Temp)

T30y25p <- hwmidLj2003$T30y25p
T30y75p <- hwmidLj2003$T30y75p
range30y <- (T30y75p - T30y25p)

#daymag<-(Temp[214:225]-hwmidFr2003$T30ymin)/(hwmidFr2003$T30ymax-hwmidFr2003$T30ymin)
#### Heat Wave occurred in Carcassonne, France, 2003

split.screen( rbind( c(0, 1, 0.6, 1), c(0, 0.5, 0, 0.6), c(0.5, 1, 0, 0.6) ) )
screen(1)
par( mar = c(2, 2, 2, 0) )
plot( c(1:365), Temp[1:365], xlim = c(1, 365), ylim = c(-10, 50),
xlab = "", ylab = "", cex.axis = 1.1, col =ifelse(Temp[1:365]>hwmiLj2003$hwmi[1:365], "red", "black"), font.axis = 2) #plot my data with points

par( new = TRUE )
plot( c(1:365), hwmiLj2003$thr[1:365], type = "l",xlim = c(1, 365),
ylim = c(-10, 50), xlab = "", ylab = "", col = 1, lwd = 2, axes = FALSE) #plot treshold
```

I tried to find an answer to my question, but somehow I didn't find anything. It is possible that I just didn't try the right keywords. If anybody knows that this is somewhere already answered/explained, you can just redirect me there.

Comment: You can't use `y` in `ifelse` like that. Try `my_x = c(1,100); my_y = c(20,40); plot(x = my_x, y = my_y, col=ifelse(my_y > 30, "red", "black"))`

Comment: I edit my question to hopefully make it more understandable.

Comment: As we cannot access your data file, please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Library in2extRemes has a data named CarcasonneHeat. But that data is slightly different than mine. Formula from help for function hwmid for that data is:                                                             data("CarcasonneHeat")
tiid <- CarcasonneHeat[2,]
Temp <- CarcasonneHeat[3, jan2003:dec2003] / 10
Tref <- CarcasonneHeat[3, jan1980:dec2011] / 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't specify `y` outside the plot command, `y>30` will be ignored.

Try for example:

```
x=1:365
y=1:365
plot(x,y,col=ifelse(y>30, "red", "black"))
```

BTW:

> `x=c(1:365), y=c(-10,50)`
>   won't work because of different lengths.

EDIT:

Now, here's a solution using a for-loop. There may be a more elegnat way, but this should work, finally.

```
pt_col <- numeric(365)
for (i in 1:365){
    if(pt_col[i]==0){
        if(Temp[i]<hwmiLj2003$thr[i]){
            pt_col[i] <- "black"
        } else if(Temp[i+1]<hwmiLj2003$thr[i+1]){
            pt_col[i] <- "black"            
        } else if(Temp[i+2]<hwmiLj2003$thr[i+2]){
            pt_col[i]="black"
        } else pt_col[c(i,i+1,i+2)]="red"
    }
}


plot( 1:365, Temp[1:365], col=pt_col)
```

Comment: Thank you for warned me to specify y outside. Why would it matter if x is not the same length that y? 
I already did what you proposed. Now I would like to color just the ones that three are over the limit.
Example: y = c(15,25,32,28,26,33,35,36). The formula that you proposed would color every point above 30, I would like to color just the last three in my example.

Comment: `ifelse(y >= y[order(-y)[3]], 2, 1)`

Comment: Thank you. 

Can you explain me the function order? I just read the help and I am not sure that I understand it. It takes the vector and than it gives you back the permutation?

Comment: Yes, it gives you the indices of the original vector, ordered from low to high. By using the minus sign we can reverse the ordering. `[3]` means the third value of the returned indices, or third highest value. Try `order(y); y[order(y)]; y[order(-y)]`.

Comment: @mateja x and y need to have the same length because every point has to coordinates, one x and y coordinate each.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation.I see that I didn't specify my question enough. 
I used your proposed formula and it doesn't work just as I would like. Sometimes it colors the points below the limit.
I would like to color three sequential points over the limit. I am trying with for, but, for now, no success.

Comment: I'd recommend right now you edit your question and give us an example of your data and the code you've tried.

Comment: Have a look at my edits. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think I've got it now. You only want red colored points if  `Temp[1:365]` of three sequential points are bigger than the three values of `hwmiLj2003$hwmi`. Maybe this could help, but theres no `Temp[1:365]` bigger than 214. Try: `thr1<-Temp[1:365]>hwmiLj2003$hwmi[,1]
thr2<-Temp[1:365]>hwmiLj2003$hwmi[,2]
thr3<-Temp[1:365]>hwmiLj2003$hwmi[,3]

plot( c(1:365), Temp[1:365], xlim = c(1, 365), ylim = c(-10, 50),
xlab = "", ylab = "", cex.axis = 1.1, col=ifelse(thr1==T,ifelse(thr2==T,ifelse(thr3==T,"red","black"),"black"),"black"), font.axis = 2)`

Comment: It is partly right. I want to color red points only if 'Temp[1:365]' of three sequential points are bigger than the relevant values of 'hwmiLj2003$thr[1:365]'. 
Values in 'hwmiLj2003$hwmi' represent value of hwmi index ('hwmiLj2003$hwmi[,1]'), length of heat wave ('hwmiLj2003$hwmi[,2]') and the day that heat wave start ('hwmiLj2003$hwmi[,3]'). 
I will try your formula with 'hwmiLj2003$thr[1:365]'.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what you exactly want to plot red. What are 'the relevant values of hwmiLj2003$thr[1:365]'?

Comment: In Temp[1:365] you have (or you suppose to have) 365 values. In hwmiLj2003$thr[1:365] you also have 365 values. Now I compare value Temp[i] with hwmiLj2003$thr[i]. If values Temp[i], Temp[i+1] and Temp[i+2] are bigger thar hwmiLj2003$[i], hwmiLj2003$[i+1] and hwmiLj2003$[i+2], than those points are red. I tried with for(i in 1:365) {plot(c(1:365), Temp[1:365], col=ifelse(Temp[i]>hwmiLj2003$[i], ifelse(Temp[i+1]>hwmiLj2003$[i+1], ifesle(Temp[i+2]>hwmiLj2003$[i+2], "red", "black"),"black"),"black")) but it colored all points in black.